# Two onClick events in React, with dispatch being one of them

Tags: reactjs

i am not sure if this is possible, and having trouble finding the answer. Basically:

```
Child component:

export function Exchanger(props, clearInputs) {
    const result = useSelector(state => state.counter.value)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    let data_1 = props.data_1; //Value of the input
    let data_2 = props.data_2; //What kind of currency
    let data_3 = props.data_3; //That currency in PLN


    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" disabled={props.disableData} aria-label="Exchange currency" onClick={
                    () =>{
                    dispatch(changeCurrency({data_1, data_2, data_3}));
                    clearInputs()
                    }
                }>
                    Exchange currency
                </button>
                &nbsp;
                <span>{ result }</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
Parent:

(other stuff here)
    const clearInputs = () => {
        setInputValue('')
        setSelectValue('default')
    }

    return(
        <>
            <Input type="number" placeholder="Type the amount in PLN" onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue} />
            <Select onChange={handleSelectChange} value={selectValue} />
            <Exchanger clearInputs={clearInputs} data_1={inputValue} data_2={selectValue} data_3={selectCurrency} disableData={disableButton} />
        </>
    )
```

I want my button to dispatch the action to the state, and then clear the inputs. The `ClearInputs()` changes state that is in the parent component. I know i can have two onClick events in my button, but is it possible if one of them is dispatch?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: I just now realised i passed down the function as an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export function Exchanger(props) {
    const { clearInputs } = props; <---
    const result = useSelector(state => state.counter.value)
```

changing this little thing fixes everything

Comment: If your own answer resolved your issue, please mark it as an Answer.

Comment: I still need to wait 19 hours to be able to do it